# Removing steps from Android back stack with cordova

Tags: android, cordova

I'm building a hybrid app with Cordova on Android and need to remove a screen from the back stack. The action performed in this case is creating an item in the app, after which the user is returned to the previous screen that initiated the action. This means the user will follow path A -> B -> A, but the back button should not allow him to return to B again. Is there any way I can remove that step from the back stack using Cordova?